# Launching ClustalX2 and a file in it from java

Tags: java, clustalx

I have successfully launch `clustalx` from java(using only `/home/b/Desktop/clustalx-2.1-linux-i686-libcppstatic/clustalx`) but cannot launch a file in it directly.
 Here are the `code`  what i have tried:

```
 String[] command= {"/home/b/Desktop/clustalx-2.1-linux-i686-libcppstatic/clustalx", "/home/b/Desktop/clustalx-2.1-linux-i686-libcppstatic/"+ "infile=F1F2CXAT211-alignment.aln" +".input"};
 String outlist[] = runCommand(command);
```

It is Running successfully without displaying clustalx.

Comment: have you try "nohup"?

Comment: I have tried "nohup" and still the program remains the same.
Try to help out with a sample code please